# c++ Recursive headers for abstract classes

Tags: c++, recursion, abstract, inheritance, inherited

Let's say I want to compile something like this:

```
//Prova.h:
//--------------------
#ifndef _PROVA_
#define _PROVA_

#include "Terza.h"

class Prova{
public:
 Prova();

};
#endif
```

and

```
//Terza.h:
//--------------------
#ifndef _TERZA_
#define _TERZA_

#include "EreProva.h"

class Terza{
public:
  Terza();
};
#endif
```

and

```
//EreProva.h:
//--------------------
#ifndef _EREPROVA_
#define _EREPROVA_

#include "Prova.h"

class EreProva : public Prova{
  public:
  EreProva();
};
#endif
```

which doesn't compile saying "'Prova' : base class undefined".

What is the best way to avoid recursion of header between inherited classes?

Comment: What's abstract about this? You should accept Aiok Save's answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to have cyclic dependencies there is something wrong with your design and you should revisit your design and try to remove such complex and unwanted cyclic dependencies.

One of overcoming cyclic dependencies is to use **[Forward Declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)**, but note that once you forward declare a type the type becomes **Incomplete type** for the compiler and there are limitations about what operations you can do with it. You cannot perform any operations on that type instances which need the compiler to know the memory layout of the type.

**Good Read:**
[When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the broken design.  **That is the important bit**, not some syntactic trick to get around it.

Comment: Let's say Terza is a map. Prova is something that want to move on that map. EreProva is a basic square of that map. To move Prova i need to know the map. To draw the map i need to use the squares.

Comment: oh i also forgot to mention that forward declaration didn't work unless i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can work around problems of this sort by tring the following: (1) try adding the "#pragma once" directive at the top of your files, although this may be compiler specific (I used it when developing in VC++ some time ago) (2) instead of including the header files in the class, you can try just add "class Prova", or whatever class it is, to indicate a class which you will define later on but want to "use" now.

Although as Als says, it is better to avoid such designs.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
//Prova.h:
//--------------------
#ifndef _PROVA_
#define _PROVA_

#include "Terza.h"

class Prova{
public:
 Prova();

};
```

Since you don't use the `Tezra` class in any way, you don't need the `#include`.  Take  it out.  Also, you are missing and #endif.  Close the `#ifndef` in this file with a matching `#endif` **in this file**.

Moreover:

```
//Terza.h:
//--------------------
#ifndef _TERZA_
#define _TERZA_

#include "EreProva.h"

class Terza{
public:
  Terza();
};
#endif

#endif
```

You also don't use the `EreProva` class in this file at all -- so take out the `#include` statement.  You also have an extra `#endif` at the end of the file.  There is only one `#ifndef` here, so there should only be one `#endif`.  Take the last one out.

Comment: i know i'm not using the includes, this was just an example

Comment: Please post actual code that demonstrates the real problem you're having.  Then we can give you better advice.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. My problem is how to compile the thing.. I need to use all the headers included. For example instantiating a variable EreProva in Terza and a variable Terza in Prova. I'd wish to know if there's some method other than rethinking the classes dependencies